# Does "way too long" mean "a lot too long" or "slightly too long"?

Tags: slang

Does *way too long* mean *a lot too long*, or *slightly too long?*

Does *way too* stand for a huge or small measure?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As an adverb, "way" means "to a great degree". So "way too long" means "very/extremely long". I also found the following information on [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Way%20Too):

> **Way too:** A phrase originating from Welland, Ontario, Canada. The phrase
>   means to do/be something to a great
>   extent.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that "way too" is a tad colloquial for formal writing.

Comment: I don't recommend using Urban Dictionary as a source.  "Way too" doesn't mean "to a great extent" — "way" means "to a great extent".  The "too" part means it is too much.  There is a difference between "way long" (which means "very long") and "way too long" (which means it is longer than it should be, by a great margin).  Also, I don't know how the origin of this phrase could be traced to Welland, Ontario.